# How to use non-continuous ranges as parameters of excel function

Tags: excel, vba, function, parameters

I have a frustrating problem using non-continuous ranges as parameters of an excel function(like slope(range_y,range_x)), how should I do that?! I have tried defining names for ranges or putting the ranges in perentheses.. but it doesn't work and I've faced #value error. I'v also tried Indirect function but no success have been achieved.  even in vba I couldn't solve this problem. please help me.
here is my code:

```
Sub Do_Interpolate_Extrapolate()
Dim X_range,Y_range As Range
Dim a_TestCell As Range
Dim FStr as String
Dim Lin_a as double  
....
Set X_range = Union(Range("V6:V7"), Range("V9:V12"), Range("V14"), Range("V17:V18"))
Set Y_range = Union(Range("T6:T7"), Range("T9:T12"), Range("T14"), Range("T17:T18"))
Set a_TestCell =Range("A2")
....
FStr = "=SLOPE(" & Y_range.Address & "," & X_range.Address & ")"
a_TestCell.Formula = FStr
Lin_a = CDbl(a_TestCell.Value)
a_TestCell.ClearContents
MsgBox "Lin_a =" & Lin_a
....
End sub
```

Running this code I get the Runtime error '1004' saying application-defined or object-defined error!

Comment: which line is throwing the error?

Comment: `Slope` does not work  on discontinuous ranges. You should make the ranges continuous using a function (making continuous arrays), temporary dropping the result in the first columns after the Used Range, use them in the function and delete them at the end. If it looks complicated, I will post an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. `Slope` needs continuous ranges. A discontinuous range address is returned like its areas separated by comma and the formula interprets each area like a parameter and 'finds' too many:

```
Sub Do_Interpolate_Extrapolate_Array()
 Dim X_range As Range, Y_range As Range
 Dim Lin_a As Double, colNo As Long, arrX, arrY
 Dim tempRngX As Range, tempRngY As Range 'temporary ranges to be created and used to calculate the slope

 colNo = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count  'the sheet existing number of columns
 Set X_range = Union(Range("V6:V7"), Range("V9:V12"), Range("V14"), Range("V17:V18"))
 Set Y_range = Union(Range("T6:T7"), Range("T9:T12"), Range("T14"), Range("T17:T18"))

 arrX = contArrayFromDscRng(X_range) 'put the content of the discontinuous range in a continuous array
 arrY = contArrayFromDscRng(Y_range) 'put the content of the discontinuous range in a continuous array
 
 cells(1, colNo + 1).Resize(UBound(arrX), 1).value = arrX 'drop the X array in the first column after the last
 cells(1, colNo + 2).Resize(UBound(arrY), 1).value = arrY 'drop the Y array in the second column after the last

 
 Set tempRngX = Range(cells(1, colNo + 1), cells(UBound(arrX), colNo + 1)) 'set the temporary X range
 Set tempRngY = Range(cells(1, colNo + 2), cells(UBound(arrY), colNo + 2)) 'set the temporary Y range

 Lin_a = WorksheetFunction.Slope(tempRngX, tempRngY) 'calculate the Slope using the temporary ranges

 tempRngX.Clear: tempRngY.Clear 'clear the temporary ranges
 MsgBox "Lin_a =" & Lin_a       'return the calculated Slope
End Sub

Private Function contArrayFromDscRng(rng As Range) As Variant 'makes an array from a discontinuous range
    Dim a As Range, arr, count As Long, i As Long
    
    ReDim arr(1 To rng.cells.count, 1 To 1): count = 1
    For Each a In rng.Areas
            For i = 1 To a.cells.count
                arr(count, 1) = a.cells(i).value: count = count + 1
            Next
    Next
    contArrayFromDscRng = arr
End Function
```

**Edited**:

The variant using (only) arrays (thanks to Chris and his idea of using `Value2` instead of `Value` - in the function:

```
Sub Do_Interpolate_Extrapolate_Array2()
 Dim X_range As Range, Y_range As Range
 Dim Lin_a As Double, colNo As Long, arrX, arrY

 colNo = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count  'the sheet existing number of columns
 Set X_range = Union(Range("V6:V7"), Range("V9:V12"), Range("V14"), Range("V17:V18"))
 Set Y_range = Union(Range("T6:T7"), Range("T9:T12"), Range("T14"), Range("T17:T18"))
 
 arrX = contArrayFromDscRng(X_range) 'put the content of the discontinuous range in a continuous array
 arrY = contArrayFromDscRng(Y_range) 'put the content of the discontinuous range in a continuous array
 
 Lin_a = WorksheetFunction.Slope(arrX, arrY) 'calculate the slope using arrays
 
 MsgBox "Lin_a =" & Lin_a                    'return the calculated Slope
End Sub
```

Faster, more compact, nicer...

Comment: @chris neilsen : This is what I had in mind and firstly tried. Theoretically, it should work. In documentation arrays are also mentioned, but I tried (2D, 1D type arrays) without being able to make it working...

Comment: @Amir Hossein Ganji: Glad I could help!

Comment: @Fane FYI, I added a array besed answer

Comment: @FaneDuru Really appreciated your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Fanes' answer

- `SLOPE` will accept Ranges, 2D arrays (single row or single column) or 1D arrays <sub>(tested in Excel365)</sub>
- `SLOPE` parameters are [`known_y's, known_x's`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/slope-function-11fb8f97-3117-4813-98aa-61d7e01276b9?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60363&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Here's a solution using Vectors

```vb
Sub Do_Interpolate_Extrapolate_Array()
    Dim X_range As Range
    Dim Y_range As Range
    Dim Lin_a As Double
    Dim arrX As Variant
    Dim arrY As Variant

    Set X_range = Union(Range("V6:V7"), Range("V9:V12"), Range("V14"), Range("V17:V18"))
    Set Y_range = Union(Range("T6:T7"), Range("T9:T12"), Range("T14"), Range("T17:T18"))

    'put the content of the non-contiguous ranges in single vectors
    arrX = VectorFromRange(X_range)
    arrY = VectorFromRange(Y_range)
 
    'calculate the Slope using the vectors
    Lin_a = WorksheetFunction.Slope(arrY, arrX)
    
    'return the calculated Slope
    MsgBox "Lin_a =" & Lin_a
End Sub


Private Function VectorFromRange(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim ar As Range
    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    ReDim arr(1 To rng.Cells.Count)
    For Each ar In rng.Areas
        For i = 1 To ar.Cells.Count
            cnt = cnt + 1
            arr(cnt) = ar.Cells(i).Value2
        Next
    Next
    VectorFromRange = arr
End Function
```

Comment: Oh! Very nice... The trick has been done by `Value2`! I had (wrongly) glued to may brain that `Value2` is inappropriate when using Date. Now I could understand that it is exactly what I needed but I did not think about it... It does not return the displayed text. I will adapt my above code in order to make it more compact/faster/nicer. i am rather busy right now, but I couldn't stop myself commenting here. Thanks! Voted up, of course... :)